# How to fadeOut div inside content div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all I've this script and I want when I click `.content` `div` fade `$('.d-menu')` element, but when I click `.d-menu` not work good, it fadeIn and fadeOut very fast :(
p.s.
`.content` is main `div`
http://jsfiddle.net/valeri879/abn8x46n/

```
<div class="f-menu"></div >
<div class="d-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
$(document.body).on('click','.f-menu',function(){
    $('.d-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});
$(document.body).on('click','.content',function (){
    $('.d-menu').fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: post your html also.

Comment: what is .content in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer below 
use event.stopPropagation();

```
 <div class="content" style="width:500px; height:500px; background:#ccc;">
        <div class="f-menu">asdasdasd</div>
        <div class="d-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document.body).on('click', '.f-menu', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('.d-menu').fadeToggle(200);
            });
            $(document.body).on('click', '.content', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('.d-menu').fadeOut(200);
            });
            $(document.body).on('click', '.d-menu', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();                   
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's work fine but when I clicked ` $('.d-menu')` element this element fadeOut  I don't want this

Comment: which element fadeout ?

Comment: `<div class="d-menu">` this `div`

Comment: There is a change in my answer. Please look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70711/discussion-between-val-kharitonashvili-and-frebin-francis).